# Function of ACP Application in AMD's Graphics Support Software?

Tags: windows, gpu, amd-radeon, amd-catalyst

What purpose does the ACP application serve on Windows with an AMD GPU? I'd rather not have another set of apps or services running if they are there for something that I don't need.

All I could search up was that one need not worry about if it's installed or not installed and one blog by w1zzard (of GPU-Z fame?) [saying it might be an "Audio Co-processor.](https://www.techpowerup.com/reviews/AMD/Radeon_Crimson_Edition_Drivers/2.html)"

> Last but not least, the "ACP Application" still hasn't received a proper description. ACP is AMD's abbreviation for Audio Co-processor (according to this redditor) and has something to do with the TrueAudio DSP. It isn't used in any notable games, so you can probably uncheck it.

Does anyone know what it actually does?

[image: AMD Crimson Installer ACP Application]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It installs a dll (amdacpusl.dll) and a Windows service (amdacpusrsvc).

AMD has been so kind to leave debug symbols in their installers, and you can clearly see lots of references to `AMD_Audio::CAudioEngine`.

I guess like you still cannot make an actual "connection" with TrueAudio, given the original DSP-based version had no public documentation.. Though what would appear to be like some kind of firmware named `dspimage_2_2_TA.bin` would really seem to point you the finger there.

**Update:** [found](http://www.overclock.net/forum/70-ati-drivers-overclocking-software/1485897-amd-catalyst-14-4-whql-driver-available-download-8.html#post22271409) an AMD PR guy confirming this. Not sure about your story saying "isn't used in notable games" (unfortunately their source seemingly deleted its comment from reddit)

Answer (score -3):

"Average CPU Power" is what its called. Audio Drivers are usually way bigger in size. I would install it as it helps to save Power and does not take up much space.

Source:

Wiki: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Average_CPU_power
AMD: http://www.amd.com/Documents/43761D-ACP_PowerConsumption.pdf#search=acp

Comment: Except those are graphics drivers, you know? And putting aside HDMI (which is certainly audio) is "big the same", there's a reason if it's called _Co-processor_ instead of something else.